# How to computer percentages and accumulated percentages with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm calculating from drivers that are involved in accidents, what percentage are in each age group, and accumulated percentage (for example drivers till age 39 are involved in 50% of all accidents)

The code below works, but I'm sure there is a more concise/efficient/clear way of doing this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age group': ['20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60 and up'], 
                   'Number accidents': [10000, 8000, 6000, 3000, 1000]})
num_accidents = sum(df['Number accidents'])
df['% accidents'] = df['Number accidents'] / num_accidents * 100
per_acc = 0
for i in df.index:
    per_acc += df.loc[i,'% accidents']
    df.loc[i,'% accidents accumulated'] = per_acc
df
```

Following is the output of the code above.

```
   Age group  Number accidents  % accidents  % accidents accumulated
0      20-29             10000    35.714286                35.714286
1      30-39              8000    28.571429                64.285714
2      40-49              6000    21.428571                85.714286
3      50-59              3000    10.714286                96.428571
4  60 and up              1000     3.571429               100.000000
```

Please help with a better way to write it

Comment: you can use :  df['accu'] = df['% accidents'].cumsum()

Comment: Cool, that worked! What about getting the initial percentage? Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, the most efficient, conside and clear way is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age group': ['20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60 and up'], 
                   'Number accidents': [10000, 8000, 6000, 3000, 1000]})
df['% accidents'] = df['Number accidents'] / df['Number accidents'].sum() * 100
df['% accidents accumulated'] = df['% accidents'].cumsum()
```

Thanks for everyone's help! Would love to hear if there are even better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum`, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html.

Then this would do the trick:

```
df['% accidents accumulated'] = df['% accidents'].cumsum()
```

Comment: You meant: 
df['% accidents accumulated'] = df['% accidents'].cumsum()
Correct?

Comment: What about getting the initial percentage? Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: It was a typo indeed, sorry. The way you calculated the initital percentages is similar to how I would do it,